# Print function printing out of order

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

Running python 3.11.2 in VSCode. I've got a simple function, and for whatever reason, it prints the last item in the fString first, on a different line, then prints the rest of the fString. Where the last item should be printed, None is printed instead.

The `filtered_sortclasses` list contains a bunch of python objects created by the `SortClass` class that I've made, I'll post that code now.

```
class SortClass:
    def __init__(self, item):
        self.common_name = item.name
        self.tier = item.tier
        self.min_price = item.price
        self.items = [item]
```

The `SortClass` class is actually called in the following code. Note that each `item` in the `auctions` list is its own class, which should not be relevant. If I need to post the code for the `Itemize` class, I can do so.

```
        sortclasses = []
        auctions = self.auctions
        
        while auctions:
            item = auctions.pop(0)
            matched = False
            
            for sc in sortclasses:
                if sc.common_name == item.name and sc.tier == item.tier:
                    matched = True
                    if item.price < sc.min_price:
                        sc.min_price = item.price
                    
                    sc.items.append(item)
                    break
            
            if not matched:
                sortclasses.append(SortClass(item))
```

Finally, the above print error occurs in the following code. Note that some of the `SortClass` objects were removed through a filtering process, but the classes themselves were not changed in any way.

```
        for sc in filtered_sortclasses:
            print(f'{sc.common_name}, {sc.tier}, {sc.min_price}, {print(sc.items)}')
            input('Continue')
```

Here's an example output:

```
[<__main__.Itemize object at 0x0000022490C3F390>,... <42 items hidden for your convenience>, <__main__.Itemize object at 0x000002248892B110>]
Auto Recombobulator, LEGENDARY, 10800000, None
```

Again, the list of items, the `class` objects, should be in the place of the `NoneType` at the end of the second output line, but instead get printed first, and are on a separate output line from everything else that is printed. This also happened when I tried replacing `{print(sc.items)}` with `{print(len(sc.items))}`. Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Comment: That's because instead of just printing `sc.items` you're calling `print` function inside another `print` function. I guess, inner function gets executed when f-string gets compiled and before it's printed out

Comment: @NotAName Guess I had a bit of a moment, I've been at it for about 5 hours lol. Thanks, if you post this as an answer I'll go ahead and accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is right here in the print statement:

```
        for sc in filtered_sortclasses:
            print(f'{sc.common_name}, {sc.tier}, {sc.min_price}, {print(sc.items)}')
            input('Continue')
```

By accident instead of simply putting `{sc.items}`, you used another `print` function inside and f-string.

As the string gets compiled, the inner `print` function gets executed before the outer one and so separately prints a part of the output while the rest of the output comes later when the outer function is executed.

So simply remove the inner `print()` and all will be fine.